# US passport, Turkish Airlines, Transfer in Instanbul, traveling in December. Visa Issues?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, turkey

I am flying Turkish Airlines from the United States to the Seychelle Islands and back in early December. USA and Turkey are in a visa hold and not issuing visas to each other at this time. Does anyone know if I might be able to visit Istanbul  during one of my 10 hour layovers?

Comment: Are you planning on leaving the transit area and entering the country? If yes, you will need to go through passport control and have a visa. If you stay within the transit area, you don't go through passport control, so wouldn't need a visa.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your inputs, I appreciate it.  I was able to talk to the Turkish Consulate today.  As @hnltraveler mentioned, I am OK if I don't leave the airport.

If I wanted to leave the airport, they suggested that I fly to Canada and obtain a visa there.   Since my layovers are only about 10 hours and I can't change my ticket, I am going to wait it out.  I may be able to do a tour on the backend return.

There is a delegation working on the issue, I will hope for the best.

https://www.oyster.com/articles/62012-u-s-and-turkey-suspend-visa-services-for-travelers/

Comment: Thanks for posting what you found out as an answer! You can merge your two accounts by clicking the "contact" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: By the way, "visa" is just an ordinary word. It's not an acronym, so there's no reason to write it in all caps.

Comment: On the backend return you can get a visa on arrival

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE (as of December 2017) : The Turkish government is once again issuing e-visas (US$20) and visa-on-arrivals (US$30) to US Citizens.**

The details below are, at this point in time, incorrect but left for historic reference.

---

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of USA can obtain a visa
>   on arrival for a maximum stay of 3 months. This does not apply
>   to nationals of the USA departing from the USA and traveling
>   directly to Turkey or transiting in a third country less than
>   24 hours

So you can get a visa on arrival at the airport visa desk if **not** arriving directly from the US, **and** having spent at least 24 hours transiting a third country. In this case, you can visit Istanbul.

Otherwise, you will be refused entry, and cannot visit Istanbul, since no visas or e-visas in advance are being issued to US citizens

**UPDATE**: Timatic's been updated, now stating:

> Visa required, except for Nationals of the USA can obtain a
>   visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 3 months. They must be
>   arriving from a country other than the USA **and have a
>   residence permit issued by the country they are arriving from.**

So Americans residing in the US can no longer get a visa on arrival at all

Comment: My understanding of the US-Turkish visa freeze was that Visa on arrival services had been suspended for US citizens.

Comment: Also, this answer does not provide a clear yes/no to the question asked.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk Called the border police at Istanbul-Atatürk airport, and it is exactly like Timatic states

Comment: [According to the Turkish Embassy](http://vasington.be.mfa.gov.tr/Mission/ShowAnnouncement/336037): "This measure [suspension of visa services] will apply to sticker visas as well as e-Visas and border visas." Turkish Airlines is reportedly [offering free changes and refunds](https://airlinegeeks.com/2017/10/17/how-the-u-s-visa-ban-could-effect-turkish-airlines/) as a result, though they say it won't impact transit passengers. As I interpret this, you might be able to get a visa at the border during your layover on the way back, but not going.

Comment: @ZachLipton Again, I spoke to the border police director (+90 212 463 30 00) - he if anyone should know 100% what practices they're applying at the border

Comment: @Crazydre I agree. I'm not the one who downvoted. Thank you for calling.